# Reinstalling pip from source distribution - shows incorect version and leaves old files

Tags: python, pip

I have a setup where I have a Windows device which is not connected to internet and all packages need to be installed from local files, including pip.
Installed python comes with pip 22.0.4. I wanted to upgrade it from source. To test it I did it in venv.
To upgrade it to higher version I downloaded zip it from repo: https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/23.1.1
To install I used :

`python -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
python setup.py install`

It was installed succesfully as venv\Scripts contained newer exe files and \venv\Lib\site-packages\pip-23.1.1-py3.10.egg was present.

The thing is if I run from venv

`pip --version`

It still shows 22.0.4 as \venv\Lib\site-packages\pip was not uninstalled when I run setup.py
Moreover if i try import pip from python and run pip.__file __ it shows me a path to \venv\Lib\site-packages\pip!
Is there a way to install from source distribution to delete previous version of package?
I may delete pip folder manually and it will show me then correct version of pip, but I am wondering is there a better and less manual way.